# Как засэтить в форме jsp переданный объект

Tags: java, spring, jsp, form, spring-mvc

Всем добрый день. Волнует такой вопрос, у меня есть объект Attend(Long id, Long studentId, String title) и Rating(Long id, Attend attend, Integer mark). Я в контроллере сэчу готовый(заполненный) объект Attend, список оценок и новый объект Rating и название страницы куда это все добро отправится.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/rating/add/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView ratingAdd(@PathVariable Long id){
    ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView();
    Attend attend = attendService.findById(id);
    Rating rating = new Rating();
    List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1;i<11;i++){
        marks.add(i);
    }
    mov.addObject("attend", attend);
    mov.addObject("marks", marks);
    mov.addObject("rating", rating);
    mov.setViewName("ratingAdd");
    return mov;
}
```

На странице я создаю форму для Rating и тут мой вопрос, как в этой форме засэтить переданный объект attend, выбрать оценку и передать готовый объект Rating в контроллер для того, что бы тот сделал запись в БД ? Я делаю это таким способом

```
<form:form action="ratingSave" method="post" modelAttribute="rating">
    <form:input type="hidden" path="id"/>
    <form:input type="hidden" path="attend"/>
    <form:label path="mark">Оценка: </form:label>
    <form:select path="mark" id="mark">
        <form:option value="0" label="Выберите оценку"/>
        <form:options items="${marks}"/>
    </form:select>
    <input type="submit" value="Поставить">
</form:form>
```

но по итогу запись в БД получается с пустым полем Attend в таблице Rating.
Если вы уже запутались) Повторю вопрос еще раз, как засэтить в jsp переданный объект в форме ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогу, решил так, отправил по обычному скрытому полю id Attend и потом в контроллере с помощью @RequestParam достал его и получил нужный мне объект

```
<form:form action="ratingSave" method="post" modelAttribute="rating">
    <form:input type="hidden" path="id"/>
    <form:label path="mark">Оценка: </form:label>
    <form:select path="mark" id="mark">
        <form:option value="0" label="Выберите оценку"/>
        <form:options items="${marks}"/>
    </form:select>
    <input type="hidden" name="attendId" value="${attendId}">
    <input type="submit" value="Поставить">
</form:form>
```

Здесь принял

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/rating/add/ratingSave"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView ratingSave(@RequestParam("attendId") String attendId, @ModelAttribute Rating rating){
    System.out.println(attendId);
    Attend attend = attendService.findById(Long.parseLong(attendId));
    rating.setAttend(attend);
    ratingService.save(rating);
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/university/profile/"+rating.getAttend().getStudent().getId()+"/student"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если правильно понял, тебе нужно, чтобы контроллер принял id, attend, rating.
Для этого можно использовать такой метод:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rating/add/{id}", method = POST)
public String view(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id,
                   @RequestParam(value = "attend") Attend attend,
                   @RequestParam(value = "rating") Rating rating,
                   Model model) {

    // Some code

    // Add elements to the jsp (use of ${})
    model.addAttribute("id", id);
    model.addAttribute("attend", attend);
    model.addAttribute("rating", rating);

    return "page";
}
```

В **@RequestParam**, *value* - пишете имя (*name*) элемента. Обратите внимание, что есть еще такой значение как *defaultValue*.

Comment: Спасибо большое, за ответ, так и сделал)